# How to list downloads from a specific browser in bash?

Tags: shell-script, ls

I'm trying to find the best way to list most recent downloads from a browser (specifically Chrome). Right now I have this bash script:

`currentDate=$(date +%m/%d/%Y) find ~/Downloads -maxdepth 1 -newermt "$currentDate"`

Which seems to work well for my cases but if I move stuff in and out of the folder, naturally it will get added to the list. I also potentially want to make it so I can filter based on which browser I used for a specific use case.

Is there a better to be handling this?

Comment: Create a separate directory for each browser :-)

Comment: @nohillside -facepalm- great idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Is there a better way" is a very highly subjective question.  That said, if you want to segregate your downloads by browser, perhaps use this structure within your home directory:

```
$ tree -d Downloads/
Downloads/
├── Chrome
├── Chromium
├── Communicator
├── curl
├── elinks
├── Firefox
├── lynx
├── Mosiac
├── Opera
└── wget
```

Comment: derp I'm not sure why I didn't think of that. Thanks haha